# Как правильно сформировать результат части формулы?

Tags: java, парсер, циклы, arraylist

Я пытаюсь реализовать парсер формул. Мне помогли разделить формулу на части

```
 public  ArrayList <String> partOfFormula(String formulaStr){
    int beginOfNextPart = 0;
    char[] formulaChars = formulaStr.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < formulaChars.length; i++) {
        if(isSign(formulaChars[i]) && (formulaChars[i] != '-' || beginOfNextPart != i)) {
            listOfParts.add(formulaStr.substring((beginOfNextPart == -1) ? 0 : beginOfNextPart, i));
            beginOfNextPart = i + 1;
        }
    }
    listOfParts.add(formulaStr.substring(beginOfNextPart, formulaStr.length()));
    return listOfParts;
}
private static boolean isSign(char c) {
    return  c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/';
}
```

Этот метод работает корректно. Теперь я пытаюсь посчитать каждую часть формулы и 
 сформировать из результата `ArrayList`<`Doable`> вот метод:

```
 public ArrayList<Double> calculateAPartOfFormula(String partOfFormula){

    partOfFormula.toLowerCase();


    String firstArgument = "";
    String secondArgument ="";

    Double firstArgumentValue = 0.0;
    Double secondArgumentValue = 0.0;

    if(!partOfFormula.contains("(")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < partOfFormula.length(); i++) {
            char ch = partOfFormula.charAt(i);
            firstArgument = firstArgument.concat("" + ch);

            firstArgumentValue = Double.valueOf(firstArgument);
        }
    }

    if (partOfFormula.contains("(")){
       int ib=partOfFormula.indexOf('(');



       int ob = partOfFormula.indexOf(')');
       for (int i =ib+1; i < ob; i++){
           char ch = partOfFormula.charAt(i);
           firstArgument = firstArgument.concat(""+ch);
           firstArgument = firstArgument.replace(")", "");
           firstArgument = firstArgument.replace(",", "");
           if (ch==','){
               ib = partOfFormula.indexOf(ch);
               for(int j =ib; j<ob; j++){
                   secondArgument = secondArgument.concat(""+partOfFormula.charAt(j));
                   secondArgument = secondArgument.replace(")", "");
                   secondArgument = secondArgument.replace(",", "");
               }
               secondArgumentValue = Double.valueOf(secondArgument);
           }

           firstArgumentValue = Double.valueOf(firstArgument);

           if(partOfFormula.contains("sin")) {
               result = Math.sin(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("cos")){
               result = Math.cos(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("tan")) {
               result = Math.tan(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("atan")) {
               result = Math.atan(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("acos")) {
               result = Math.acos(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("asin")) {
               result = Math.asin(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("^")) {
               result = Math.pow(firstArgumentValue, secondArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("exp")) {
               result = Math.exp(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (!firstArgument.contains("(")) {
               result = Double.valueOf(firstArgument);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           }
    }


    return resultsOfParts;


   }
```

Я передаю в метод `partOfFormula` строку

```
"sin(30)*cos(60)/2"
```

И он возвращает

```
sin(30)
cos(60)
2
```

То есть по идее мой метод `calculateAPartOfFormula` должен вернуть три `ArrayList` , так как я вызываю его таким образом:

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayList = f.partOfFormula("sin(30)*cos(60)/2");

for(int i = 0; i< arrayList.size();i++) {
    System.out.println(f.calculateAPartOfFormula(arrayList.get(i)));
}
```

Но этот метод возвращает намного больше `ArrayList`

```
  [0.1411200080598672, 3.0, -0.9880316240928618, 30.0]
  [0.1411200080598672, 3.0, -0.9880316240928618, 30.0, 0.960170286650366, 6.0, -0.9524129804151563, 60.0]
  [0.1411200080598672, 3.0, -0.9880316240928618, 30.0, 0.960170286650366, 6.0, -0.9524129804151563, 60.0]
  [0.1411200080598672, 3.0, -0.9880316240928618, 30.0, 0.960170286650366, 6.0, -0.9524129804151563, 60.0, 0.1411200080598672, 3.0, -0.9880316240928618, 30.0]
  [0.1411200080598672, 3.0, -0.9880316240928618, 30.0, 0.960170286650366, 6.0, -0.9524129804151563, 60.0, 0.1411200080598672, 3.0, -0.9880316240928618, 30.0, 0.960170286650366, 6.0, -0.9524129804151563, 60.0]
  [0.1411200080598672, 3.0, -0.9880316240928618, 30.0, 0.960170286650366, 6.0, -0.9524129804151563, 60.0, 0.1411200080598672, 3.0, -0.9880316240928618, 30.0, 0.960170286650366, 6.0, -0.9524129804151563, 60.0]
```

Помогите найти ошибку

Полный код класса

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.HashMap;

  public class Formula extends  Object {

private HashMap <String, Double> partsOfFormulaHashMap = new HashMap<>();

private Double result;

private String formulaStr;
private char [] charsOfFormula;
private String formulaVariable;
private String [] partsOfFormulaArray;

private ArrayList<String> listOfParts = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Double> resultsOfParts = new ArrayList<>();

public Formula (String formulaStr, String formulaVariable){
    formulaStr.toLowerCase();

    this.formulaStr = formulaStr;
    this.formulaVariable = formulaVariable;

}

public  ArrayList <String> partOfFormula(String formulaStr){
    int beginOfNextPart = 0;
    char[] formulaChars = formulaStr.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < formulaChars.length; i++) {
        if(isSign(formulaChars[i]) && (formulaChars[i] != '-' || beginOfNextPart != i)) {
            listOfParts.add(formulaStr.substring((beginOfNextPart == -1) ? 0 : beginOfNextPart, i));
            beginOfNextPart = i + 1;
        }
    }
    listOfParts.add(formulaStr.substring(beginOfNextPart, formulaStr.length()));
    return listOfParts;
}
private static boolean isSign(char c) {
    return  c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/';
}


public ArrayList<Double> calculateAPartOfFormula(String partOfFormula){

    partOfFormula.toLowerCase();


    String firstArgument = "";
    String secondArgument ="";

    Double firstArgumentValue = 0.0;
    Double secondArgumentValue = 0.0;

    if(!partOfFormula.contains("(")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < partOfFormula.length(); i++) {
            char ch = partOfFormula.charAt(i);
            firstArgument = firstArgument.concat("" + ch);

            firstArgumentValue = Double.valueOf(firstArgument);
        }
    }

    if (partOfFormula.contains("(")){
       int ib=partOfFormula.indexOf('(');



       int ob = partOfFormula.indexOf(')');
       for (int i =ib+1; i < ob; i++){
           char ch = partOfFormula.charAt(i);
           firstArgument = firstArgument.concat(""+ch);
           firstArgument = firstArgument.replace(")", "");
           firstArgument = firstArgument.replace(",", "");
           if (ch==','){
               ib = partOfFormula.indexOf(ch);
               for(int j =ib; j<ob; j++){
                   secondArgument = secondArgument.concat(""+partOfFormula.charAt(j));
                   secondArgument = secondArgument.replace(")", "");
                   secondArgument = secondArgument.replace(",", "");
               }
               secondArgumentValue = Double.valueOf(secondArgument);
           }

           firstArgumentValue = Double.valueOf(firstArgument);

           if(partOfFormula.contains("sin")) {
               result = Math.sin(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("cos")){
               result = Math.cos(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("tan")) {
               result = Math.tan(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("atan")) {
               result = Math.atan(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("acos")) {
               result = Math.acos(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("asin")) {
               result = Math.asin(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("^")) {
               result = Math.pow(firstArgumentValue, secondArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (partOfFormula.contains("exp")) {
               result = Math.exp(firstArgumentValue);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           if (!firstArgument.contains("(")) {
               result = Double.valueOf(firstArgument);
               resultsOfParts.add(result);
           }
           }
    }

    System.out.println(resultsOfParts.size());
    return resultsOfParts;


}

public void viewParts (){

    for(String part: listOfParts){
        System.out.println(part);
    }

}

 }
```

Для запуска

```
 public class MainWindow  MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 

 privete JButton graphicsButton = new JButton ();
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   graphicsButton.addActionListner(this);
   MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
   main.setMinimumSize(new Dimansion (600, 600));
}

   @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

if (e.getSource() == graphicsButton){
GraphicsWindow graphicDialog = new GraphicsWindow().create();
Formula f = new Formula("sin(30)*cos(60)/2", "x");
f.partOfFormula("sin(30)*cos(60)/2");
f.viewParts();

ArrayList<String> arrayList = f.partOfFormula("sin(30)*cos(60)/2");
ArrayList<Double> arrayList1 = f.calculateAPartOfFormula(arrayList.get(0));


}
```

Comment: чтобы ваш код отладить, надо его запустить, а в текущем виде он просто не компилируется. оценить логику кода, который первый раз видишь, да еще и не полностью, на глаз - задачка еще та.

Comment: @Дмитрий Могу добавить полный код. Сейчас отредактирую

Comment: @Дмитрий добавил.

Comment: Вы бы ф-ции хотя бы использовали, что-ли. Накидал скелет, надо?

Comment: У вас здесь треш полный. Переменные инициализруются в конструкторе и никогда не используются. методы вызываются, а значения игнорируются (partOfFormula.toLowerCase();), даже условные оператор написан странно (два ифа вместо if - else)... вам надо с этим что-то делать, в пртивном случае все, что сложнее 2+2 будет даваться с болью

Comment: @Дмитрий  partOfFormula.toLowerCase() игнорируется сейчас. Я планирую вводить строку в текстовое поле и получать формулу из него. Переменные в конструкторе не используются тоже пока.

Comment: Ваш метод calculateAPartOfFormula делает следующее. Срабатывает условие  if (partOfFormula.contains("(")), после чего цикл исполняется 2 раза. в каждом из циклов отрабатывает условие на синус и на открытые скобки. при этом перввый раз синус рассчитывается из 3 и записывается в массив 0,14, а закрытые скобки добавляют саму 3, а второй раз все тоже самое происходит но уже со значением 30, в результате в коллекцию также попадают синус из 30 -0,98 и сама 30. в чем тут сокральный смысл и зачем вы берете сначала 3, а уже потом 30, если синус нужен только из 30, вам виднее.  итог-0,14, 3, -0,98, 30.

Comment: Изучите для начала стек и обратную польскую запись. То что получилось лучше выкинуть.